# What is IPv6 connection sharing and why do I want it?

Tags: networking, ipv6, airport

I can't easily find any good information on what IPv6 connection sharing *is*, nor how it affects my local network topology. I can only find a bunch of [information](https://www.google.com/search?q=ipv6%20connection%20sharing) on how to enable it and how turning it off fixes problems.

My setup is one "main" airport extreme (6th gen), with an airport extreme (4th gen) and an airport express set up as repeaters. I'm assuming that I'd only need to enable ipv6 sharing on the main one, since I read that they use [ipv6 as a fallback](https://superuser.com/a/387831/243446) (but I probably misunderstood this functionality). I also have a local DNS server on a raspberry pi running dnsmasq, if that's something I also need to configure.

From what I've read, it seems like turning on IPv6 could impart some performance benefits if your ISP provisions an IPv6 IP to you, and that IPv6 allows devices on your home network to all have unique, internet-addressable IP's (which is why the AEBS has "block incoming ipv6 connections" enabled by default). Is this what is meant by IPv6 connection sharing?

**EDIT:** Is this at all related to the standard notion of connection sharing, where one device has a connection to the internet (e.g. a laptop with wireless), and the internet connection can then be shared with another device that doesn't have wireless? If that's the case I don't understand why a router would call it "connection sharing" because that's the whole point of a router, to share a connection to the WAN (internet) with the LAN. If that's the case, is there some new notion of the router becoming a device (or node) in the internet with IPv6 that wasn't the case with IPv4? To my understanding, with IPv4, in a common network setup, the router has one IPv4 address assigned from the ISP (like 76.13.xx.xx), and then would provide and route requests to the internal network (with addresses like 192.168.x.x), so to the outside there's only one IP address although several devices are using that connection.

Comment: Unfortunately, "user centered" devices often use some "easy" terminology that make it difficult to find out what it really does. I don't own an airport extreme, so I don't know and can't find out what it does, but suppose it could do anything from network address translation (NAT), for IPv4 and/or IPv6, to providing it's own IPv6 prefix, to just routing. I guess you'd need root access or equivalent to the device to find out ...

Comment: Technically routers do packet routing. And NAT does the connection sharing.