# Which IPv6 mode would make my WiFi the fastest?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ipv6, airport, airport-extreme

I've tried looking this up, but can't find much about it. I'm just wondering what option would make my WiFi the fastest - if any at all. I'm currently using the Apple AirPort Utility, and I went into the settings for my main WiFi port. When I went into the Advanced settings, I found something about IPv6. There are four options for the IPv6 Mode:

- Link Local Only
- Host
- Tunnel
- Router

I don't think the tunnel would make it faster, as I kind of know what tunnels do. As for the other three, I have no clue. If someone could tell me which one would work and why, it would be GREATLY appreciated...

Thanks again, EofTheN

Comment: The used IP protocol has nothing to do with your speed, it's like asking which street and # will make your car go faster

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between the IPv6 options in AirPort Utility?](https://superuser.com/questions/244395/what-are-the-differences-between-the-ipv6-options-in-airport-utility)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These settings have nothing to do with the speed of your connection. If you are having speed/local interference issues change the channel of the wireless in the router to one that is less congested.

Checking out the specifics on your client side wireless devices can also help. If they use 40mhz wide channels and up, mimo / mu-mimmo and the fastest technology features both AP and client device support will help the most.

Hope this helps